# rock, paper, scissor app using javascript, can't display correctly

Tags: javascript

i'm learning javascript and currently making a rock, paper, scissor game using only javascript. the game will have 1 round mode and 3 rounds mode but as i finished to code the 1 round mode i found out having problem display result, whoever win the game it display "the game is tie" and can't find where s the mistake, can anybody help me?

```
    // Player choice 

var getPlayerChoice = function() {
  var playerChoice = prompt("Choose rock, paper, or scissors");
  while (playerChoice !== 'rock' && playerChoice !== 'paper' && playerChoice !== 'scissors') {
    if (playerChoice === null) {
      break;
    }
    playerChoice = prompt("Invalid ! you have to choose rock, paper, or scissors");
  }
  return playerChoice;
}

// Computer Choice 

var getComputerChoice = function () {
  var randomNum = Math.random();
  if ( randomNum < 0.3333 ) {
    return "rock";
  } else if ( randomNum > 0.3333 && randomNum < 0.6666 ) {
    return "scissors";
  } else {
    return "paper";
  }
}

// Winner Function 

var getWinner = function (playerChoice, computerChoice) {
  if (computerChoice === playerChoice) {
    return "The Game is Tie";
  } else if (computerChoice === "paper") {
    if (playerChoice === "scissors") {
      return "player win";
    } else if (playerChoice === "rock") {
      return "computer win";
    }
  } else if (computerChoice === "rock") {
    if (playerChoice === "scissors") {
      return "computer win";
    } else if (playerChoice === "paper") {
      return "player win";
    }
  } else if (computerChoice === "scissors") {
    if (playerChoice === "rock") {
      return "player win";
    } else if (playerChoice === "paper") {
      return "computer win";
    }
  }
}

// Single game mode 

var singleRound = function() {
  var playerChoice = getPlayerChoice();
  if (playerChoice === null) {
    return;
  }
  
  var computerChoice = getComputerChoice();
  
  var winner = getWinner(playerChoice, computerChoice);
  var message = " You chose: " + playerChoice + "\n Computer chose: " + computerChoice;
  if (winner === "player") {
    alert(message + "\nYou won!");
  } else if (winner === "computer") {
    alert(message + "\nYou lost!");
  } else {
    alert(message + "\nThe Game is Tie");
  }
  return winner;
}

var mode = prompt("Welcome!\n \nplease insert 1 for single round mode\n2 for 3 rounds mode");
if (mode === '1') {
  singleRound();
} else if (mode === '2') {
  threeRoundsMode();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `getWinner()` function returns `player win` or `computer win`, but your code that calls it is looking for return values of `player` or `computer`.

Because the code never gets what it's looking for it defaults to `'The Game is Tie'

Comment: Need to change `if (winner === "player")` to `if (winner === "player win")` and change `if (winner === "computer")` to `if (winner === "computer win")`.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because of a mistake in the singleRound() function. `if (winner === "player") {` should be `if (winner === "player win") {` and similarly the `if (winner === "computer") {` should say `if (winner === "computer win") {` so that the text being compared matches. Right now, it is comparing "player" and "player win", then "computer" and "computer win" so then the else clause is reached regardless of actual game outcome.